# Tailwind Elements Select component not working with Angular *ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular, tailwind-elements

Here is my codes for basic angular component where I'm using Tailwind Elemets CSS framework.

app.componenets.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Select, Datepicker, Input, initTE } from "tw-elements";

@Component({
selector: 'app-root',
templateUrl: './app.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
title = 'test-tailwind-elements';

ngOnInit(): void {
    initTE({ Datepicker, Input, Select });
}

fruitsList: { name: string[] }[] = [
    {
    name: ['Mango', 'Papaya', 'Banana']
    },
    {
    name: ['Mango', 'Papaya', 'Banana']
    },
    {
    name: ['Mango', 'Papaya', 'Banana']
    }
]
}
```

app.component.html

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Fruits</th>
    </tr>
    <!-- <tr *ngFor="let item of fruitsList;"> -->
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select data-te-select-init>
                <option value="1">Mango</option>
                <option value="2">Papaya</option>
                <option value="3">Banana</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The issue I'm facing at here is, if we don't use `*ngFor` with `<tr>` html tag then it render the output properly. But, the moment we use that along with `*ngFor` it don't render properly.

Here are some screenshots for reference

Select dropdown working
[image]

Select dropdown not working
[image]

I feel like with *ngFor when inside a loop it's creating the dropdown list somehow it's can't able to register the components with DOM. But, I can't able to understand how to fix this.

Need some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's due to initialising the components in `ngOnInit`, before the selects are ready with `data-te-select-init`, so they never get initialised. Change to using `AfterViewInit` and it works fine.

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Select, Datepicker, Input, initTE } from "tw-elements";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  title = 'test-tailwind-elements';

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    initTE({ Datepicker, Input, Select });
  }

  fruitsList: { name: string[] }[] = [
    {
      name: ['Mango', 'Papaya', 'Banana']
    },
    {
      name: ['Mango', 'Papaya', 'Banana']
    },
    {
      name: ['Mango', 'Papaya', 'Banana']
    }
  ]
}
```

Here's a [working version in a repo](https://github.com/pecknigel/angular-tw-elements-experimentation/tree/2a87fba86a874bf391981f7de774f09cdd0c89a6).

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing all these in such a details. It's working now. I didn't know about this ```ngAfterViewInit```. I need to check this & similar other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you’re applying the `ngFor` in the wrong place. Apply it to the `option` (the thing that needs repeating for each item) and you should get the results that you’re looking for.

Something like…

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Fruits</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select data-te-select-init>
                <option *ngFor="let item of fruitsList;" value="{{item.value}}">{{item.name}}</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And in the component:

```
fruitsList: { value: string, name: string }[] = [
    {
        value: '1',
        name: 'Mango'
    },
    {
        value: '2',
        name: 'Papaya'
    },
    {
        value: '3',
        name: 'Banana'
    },
]
```

Comment: Thanks for this quick reply. Sorry, my input data seems giving a wrong impression about what I want to achieve.  Actually, I'm trying to create multiple SELECT dropdown buttons using ```*ngFor``` & I'm facing this issue. So, the place where I'm using the ```*ngFor``` is the right one.

Comment: I added a new answer that fixes that.